# κ̄₀ for Mercury—Formula (BIS—Different definition of the term/angle)

Tags: trigonometry, math-history, mathematical-astronomy, celestial-mechanics

Following [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4832793/%ce%ba%e2%82%80-for-mercury-formula) about a specific “hidden” formula in Ptolemy’s model for Mercury, I am now looking for yet another “hidden” formula, this time the one used to find $\bar\kappa_0$ so that $OC=60$ in the figure below. We are given that $DC=60$ (in arbitrary units), that angles $AFD$ and $AEC$ are equal but of opposite direction (so $\angle AFD = -\angle AEC$), and that $OE=EF=FD$ (which is equal to 3, but I’d like to keep 3 out of the equation and just symbolize it by *e* (for “eccentricity”).

($A$ is the apogee of Mercury’s *deferent* centered on $D$. $D$ rides on the small circle centered on $F$. The Earth is at point $O$ [for “observer”]. Points $O$, $E$, and $F$ are always in a straight line with $A$. Mercury itself rides on the *epicycle* centered on $C$.)

While Ptolemy knew of absolutely no trigonometry and other modern mathematics, I don’t mind the answer to be expressed in modern terms, although simple trigonometry would be nice since math is not my forte.

[image]

P.S. I’ll also ask this question on AstronomySE.

Comment: If everything is the same except $DF=FE=EO=e$, then I got $-6e^2\cos^3\bar{\kappa_0} + (3600-4e^2)\cos^2\bar{\kappa_0} + 2e^2\cos\bar{\kappa_0} - e^2=0$. However, I realized $OC=60$ which you didn't have in your other question, which means the above new cubic equation is not what you want. I think that even if you got a new equation with $OC=60$, substituting $e=3$ into the new equation would not give you the equation we already have in your other question. Are you sure that you are asking a different question with $OC=60$?

Comment: @mathlove: Thank you for this. Yes, it is indeed a different question with $OC=60$ here. In my other question, $OC$ was approximately 56.7, but we knew $\kappa_0$ whereas here we are looking for $\kappa_0$ when $OC=60$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a quartic equation.

In the following, I'm going to show how I got the quartic equation.

Let $x:=\bar{\kappa_0}$ and $c:=\cos x$.

Let $G$ be the intersection point of $EF$ with $CD$.

Let $H$ be a point on $EF$ such that $DH\perp EF$.

Let $I$ be a point on $EF$ such that $CI\perp EF$.

Applying the law of sines to $\triangle{CEO}$, we have
$$\frac{60}{\sin(180-x)}=\frac{e}{\sin C}=\frac{CE}{\sin(x-C)}$$
So, $$CE=\sqrt{3600-e^2(1-c^2)}-ec\tag1$$

Applying the law of sines to $\triangle{DFG}$, we have
$$\sin\angle{DGF}=\frac{e\sin x}{DG}\tag2$$

Applying the law of sines to $\triangle{CEG}$, we have
$$\sin\angle{CGE}=\frac{CE\sin x}{60-DG}\tag3$$

From $(2)(3)$, we get
$$\frac{e\sin x}{DG}=\frac{CE\sin x}{60-DG}$$
so
$$DG=\frac{60e}{CE+e}\tag4$$

Applying the law of cosines to $\triangle{FDG}$, we have
$$DG^2=e^2+FG^2-2\cdot e\cdot FGc$$
which can be written as
$$DG^2-FG^2=e^2-2ecFG\tag5$$

Applying the law of cosines to $\triangle{CEG}$, we have
$$(60-DG)^2=(e+FG)^2+CE^2-2CE(e+FG)c$$
which can be written as
$$DG^2-FG^2=-3600+120DG+e^2+2eFG+CE^2-2CE(e+FG)c\tag6$$

From $(5)(6)$, we get
$$e^2-2ecFG=-3600+120DG+e^2+2eFG+CE^2-2CE(e+FG)c$$
$$FG=\frac{-3600+120DG+CE^2-2ecCE}{-2ec-2e+2CEc}=\frac{-2 e c y^2 - 2 e^2 c y + y^3 + e y^2 - 3600 y + 3600 e}{(y + e) (2c y - 2e c - 2e)}\tag7$$
where $y:=CE$.

Since $\triangle{GHD}\sim\triangle{GIC}$, we have
$$DH:CI=GH:GI\tag8$$
Since $DH=e\sin x,CI=CE\sin x$ and $GI=HI-GH=(EI-EH)-GH=CE\cos x-(EF+FH)-GH=CE\cos x-e-e\cos x-GH$, it follows from $(8)$ that
$$GH=\frac{yce-e^2
-e^2c}{y+e}$$

So, we get
$$FG=FH+GH=ec+\frac{yce-e^2
-e^2c}{y+e}\tag9$$

It follows from $(7)(9)$ that
$$\frac{-2 e c y^2 - 2 e^2 c y + y^3 + e y^2 - 3600 y + 3600 e}{(y + e) (2c y - 2e c - 2e)}=ec+\frac{yce-e^2
-e^2c}{y+e}$$
So,
$$4 e c^2 y + 2 e c y - 2 e^2 c - y^2 - 2 e y - 2 e^2 + 3600=0$$

which can be written as
$$\sqrt{3600-e^2+e^2c^2}=\frac{e(4 c^3 + 4 c^2 + 1)}{4 c^2  + 4 c - 2}$$
Squaring the both sides, we finally get
$$\color{red}{(32 e^2 - 57600)\cos^4\kappa_0 + (56 e^2 - 115200)\cos^3\kappa_0 + 4 e^2 \cos^2\kappa_0+(- 16 e^2  + 57600)\cos\kappa_0 + 5 e^2 - 14400=0}$$

Comment: Oooh awesome! :) Thank you so much! :) On top of that, isolating $R=60$ in there seems really easy, so I don’t even need to ask for a generic formula! :)